# Closeable extends AutoCloseable

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I was recently going through the src.zip file of jdk 1.8 and found out something quite odd.

```
public interface Closeable extends AutoCloseable
```

and since ***AutoCloseable*** is an *interface* as well, how is anything in java allowed to ***extend*** it?

When i tried it with any other interfaces, i was constantly getting the error message :

> The type Runnable cannot be the superclass of ***userDefine Class***; a superclass must be a class.

So, why this discrepancy? or am i missing something ? If so, please explain it to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java why interface extends interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437131/java-why-interface-extends-interface)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just think of it in terms of natural language, interfaces can *extend* other interfaces because they are *extending* the requirements they give to an implementing class. They are *more specific* contracts.

If an interface were to use the `implements` keyword to express this idea then it would be confusing. 'Implements' means 'to provide an implementation' and that's not what's happening here.

Hence:

1. interfaces can extend interfaces
2. classes can extend classes
3. classes can implement interfaces

Answer (score 2):

> **Interfaces `extends` interfaces.** Not `implements`.

When inheriting, you use the keyword `extends`, both when a class inherits from a class or an interface inherits from another interface.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to interfaces, the keyword `extends` can be seen as `implements` for classes.

This will add the capabilites of the super interface to the extendee